# Rails Routing Based on Session Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, routes

For a specific URL, we want to redirect ONLY users in a certain state (defined by `session[:state_code]` to be directed to a new URL.

All other users should see and redirected to the old URL. How can we do this effectively in Rails? We can't access the session from a route constraint. For complex issues I won't get into, we need to do this redirect in routes.rb and not perform this in the controller.

Answer (score 6):

You could access session throw request parameter - `request.session`.

Example:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: redirect('<specific URL>'), constraints: lambda { |request|
    request.session[:state_code] == <specific value>
  }
  root to: redirect('<old URL>'), as: 'root_old'
end
```

For different possibilities to declare advanced constraints look in Rails official doc - [Advanced Constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

The same could be achieved by providing a block to `redirect` (for more details see [Redirection](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)):

Example:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: redirect{ |path_params, request|
    request.session[:state_code] == <specific value> ? '<specific URL>' : '<old URL>'
  }
end
```

Comment: Getting `ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'` on Rails 6.

Comment: @thisismydesign thank you for your comment. Break modification was introduced by issue https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34494. So to fix it, you just need to assign manual `as:` parameter for some of the route. Fix my post with such modification.

Comment: Thanks! I used `get '/', to: '...', constraints: ...` for 1 of the routes. The only limitation I can think of for both approaches is, not sure if I could always call `root_path` or only if it's defined simply via `root`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on some something similar. As far as I understand, what you are specifically wanting to do is not possible, or at least easily. The issue is that the routes.rb has not knowledge of the sessions 'hash' so there is no way to look it up.

http://bjedrocha.com/rails/2015/03/18/role-based-routing-in-rails/

This blog helped me, and the alternative is to persist the user state in the database. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just use request.session[:state_code] as @ych suggests

`get('/your_route', constraints: AuthenticatedConstraint.new, to: redirect do |_p, req|
    req.flash[:error] = 'not_authorized
    '/'
  end)`

and define `AuthenticatedConstraint` in `app/constraints` with `def matches?(request)` that returns `true/false`